# R: categorical + numeric in knn with caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, knn, categorical-data

I am trying to run `knn` with a dataset with both categorical and numeric variables.

It seems that the categorical variables need to be converted into numeric or dummies, but I am wondering if this can be done within `caret`'s `method` option.

```
DOW = weekdays(sample(seq(as.Date('2019/01/01'), as.Date('2019/05/01'), by="day"), 20))
apple = sample(1:100, 20, replace = T)
peach = sample(1:20, 20, replace = T)
cherry =sample(1:1000, 20, replace = T)
money= rnorm(20, 100, 20)

dt = data.frame(money, DOW, apple, peach, cherry)
```

Here is my `knn` code - this was taken out from my original project with `pca` and other loops applied. Ideally I would keep `caret` function but any advice is appreciated!

```
  train.control=trainControl(method='cv', preProcOptions = list(thresh=0.8))
  k = train(knn_y~., method='knn', 
            tuneGrid=expand.grid(k=1:10), 
            trControl=train.control, preProcess=c('scale','center','pca'),
            metric='RMSE', data=data.frame(knn_y=knn_y, this.train))
```